# Rendered attribute for Boolean type is not working in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using rendered attribute for p:graphicImage. In that i am checking a field which is boolean type             . Rendered is not working for this boolean type. In DB this field is BIT type.

In DB, value for this field is 1. Default value in DB is 0. When i give as != 0 in rendered, it is showing as true and for == 0 in rendered, it is showing true itself. 
What is the syntax for checking boolean type in rendered attribute in primefaces?

Below is my code:

```
  <p:graphicImage value="/Images/abc.png"  
        rendered="#{!(MedicineList.goal eq '0')}">

  </p:graphicImage>
```

In above code, MedicineList is dataTable's variable and goal is the field which is BIT type in mysql.
Thanks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is BIT(1) type.Instead of '0' what should be used?

Comment: goal is boolean type in java.Just now i checked the pojo.sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `BIT` type in `MySQL` then `0` is for `false` and `1` is for `true`. So try using it like.

```
<p:graphicImage value="/Images/abc.png"  
        rendered="#{not MedicineList.goal}">

</p:graphicImage>
```

Also the return type of `goal` function should `boolean`.

Comment: sorry @Qadir Hussain, your answer is not working.Actually my issue is if goal is 1 then only the image shoud be shown

Comment: If DB model has `bit` and `goal` function returns `boolean` the just use as `rendered="#{MedicineList.goal}"`.